# I am unable to access an asp.net mvc controller to return me a JsonResult using $resource of angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

What am I missing ? I am new to Angularjs. Trying angularjs with asp.net mvc. I am unable to access an asp.net mvc controller to return me a JsonResult using $resource of angular.
However, I get success otherwise using $.getJson of javascript but not using angularjs. What am I missing ? please guide. Thank you for replying any.

Following is my Service

```
EbsMvcApp.factory('classListService', function ($resource, $q)
{
    var resource = $resource
                    (
                      '/Home/ClassList' 
                      , {}
                     //{ method: 'Get', q: '*' }, // Query parameters
                       , { 'query': { method: 'GET' , isArray:false  } }
                    );

    function get($q)
    {
        console.log('Service: classListServic > Started');

        var Defered = $q.defer();

        resource.get
            (
                 function (dataCb)
                 {
                     console.log('success in http service call');
                     Defered.resolve(dataCb);
                 }
                , function (dataCb)
                {
                    console.log('error in http service')
                    Defered.reject(dataCb);
                }
            );
        return Defered.promise; // if missed, would throw an error on func: then.
    };
    return { get: get };
});
```

angular Controller:

```
var EbsMvcApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

//'classListService',
EbsMvcApp.controller
    (
        'myAppController',
        ['$scope','classListService','$q' , function ($scope, classListService, $q)
            {
                    console.log('controller myAppController started');

                    var classList = classListService.get($q);
                   classList =  classList.then( 

                        function ()
                        {
                            (
                            function (response)
                            {
                                console.log('class list function response requested');
                                return response.data;
                            }
                        );
                       }
                    );

                   console.log(classList.ClassName);
                   console.log(classList);

                    console.log('end part of ctrl');
                    $scope.classList = classList;
                    $scope.SelectedClassID = 0;
                    $scope.message = ' message from Controller ';

            }
        ]
    );
```

Asp.net MVC Controller

```
namespace EBS_MVC.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

                public JsonResult ClassList()
            {
                var List = new SelectList(db.tblClass, "ID", "ClassName");

                return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
       }
    }
```

Brower's response (F12):

ControllerTry1.js:11 controller myAppController started
serviceGetClassList.js:16 Service: classListServic > Started
ControllerTry1.js:28 undefined
ControllerTry1.js:29 c
ControllerTry1.js:31 end part of ctrl
angular.js:12520 Error: [$resource:badcfg] 
[Browers response: screen shot][1]

Comment: Im not familiar with angular $resource but I can see that the code you have in the 'then' part for classListService.get() in your controller is passing in an anonymous function which inside of that is just declaring an anonymous function that has a response parameter. You need to remove the outer anonymous function to have the code execute as you would expect, also the console.log lines in your controller may run before the result has come back from the service resulting in 'undefined' results in your console as the promise has not yet been resolved.

Comment: oky, I have removed that pointed out anonymous funciton, but the result is same . with following log: 1- controller myAppController started 2-Service: classListServic > Started 3-undefined 4-c (empty object) 5-end part of ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Oky, finally,  I got a solution using the $http service. from here

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/13/how-to-use-angularjs-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework-4.aspx

in csHtml file, a reference to the service.js and Controler.js is required.
I am not sure if I have added it earlier or later now. but its required.

ng-Controller:

```
    EbsMvcApp.controller('ClassListController', function ($scope, ClassListService2) {    

            console.log('ClassListController Started');

            GetClassList();

            function GetClassList()
            {
                ClassListService2.GetJson()
                        .success(function (dataCallBack) {
                            $scope.classList = dataCallBack;
                            console.log($scope.classList);
                        })
                        .error(function (error) {
                            $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
                            console.log($scope.status);
                        });
            }
        });
```

ng-Service:

```
    EbsMvcApp.factory('ClassListService2', ['$http', function ($http) {


    console.log('ClassListService2 Started');

    var list = {};
    list.GetJson = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/ClassList');
    };
    return list;

}]);
```

csHtml View:

```
    <div class="text-info" ng-controller="ClassListController">
<h3> Text from Controller: </h3>

@*table*@
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>DisplayName</th><th>Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-hide="classList.length">
            <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in classList">
            <td>{{item.Text}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Value}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I just wrote up some code to quickly test the ngResource module as I haven't used it yet.

I've got the code working to do what you want using the ngResource module. I think part of the problem was that you was configuring the query method but calling the get method so your configurations was not applied.

Here is the service class that  I wrote to test against a controller the same as yours.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .service('classService', ClassService);

    ClassService.$inject = ['$resource', '$q'];

    function ClassService($resource, $q) {

        var resource = $resource
        (
            '/Home/ClassList',
            {},
            {
                'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
            }
        );

        var service = {
            get: get
        };

        return service;

        ////////////

        function get() {
            var Defered = $q.defer();

            resource.get(function (dataCb) {
                console.log('success in http service call');
                Defered.resolve(dataCb);
            }, function (dataCb) {
                console.log('error in http service')
                Defered.reject(dataCb);
            });

            return Defered.promise;
        };
    };
})();
```

The controller looks like this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('classController', ClassController);

    ClassController.$inject = ['$scope', 'classService'];

    function ClassController($scope, classService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.data = null;

        activate();

        /////////////

        function activate() {

            var classList = classService.get().then(function (response) {
                console.log('class list function response requested');
                vm.data = response;
                console.log(vm.data);
            });

            console.log('end part of ctrl');
            $scope.SelectedClassID = 0;
            $scope.message = ' message from Controller ';
        };

    };
})();
```

I've included some of your original code just so you can see how it would fit in.

Glad to see you have got it working though!

Comment: I am glad you replied and used $resource, my believe in $resource is back :)